# jQuery Loader on a Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, loader

I am creating an application in Node, which pulls objects in my Schema (Mongo) and presents them in HTML. Okay, all right so far.

Now I need to create a jQuery loader, which features a picture like this while the objects do not appear in the html -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQc8d.gif while the data does not appear.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: host + '/datas',
    success:function(datas) {
        datas.forEach (function (data) {
            var HTML = [];
            HTML.push('<tr class="datas">');
            HTML.push('<td>' + data.email + '</td>');
            HTML.push('<td>' + name.email + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('</tr>');
            $('tbody').append(reservasHTML.join(''));
        })
    }
});
```

How I can do this?

Comment: i answer the question, i think this is it..

Comment: Before request show loading image, after append all data hide loading image. What hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({

    $(".datas").empty().html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hq37Dew.gif" />'); // SHOW THE AJAX LOADER
    type: 'GET',
    url: host + '/datas',
   success:function(datas){
        $(".datas").html(datas); // this will hide the loader and replace it with the data                            

        datas.forEach (function (data) {

            var HTML = [];
            HTML.push('<tr class="datas">');
            HTML.push('<td>' + data.email + '</td>');
            HTML.push('<td>' + name.email + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('</tr>');
            $('tbody').append(reservasHTML.join(''));

        })
   }
});
```

I think this is it.

Comment: i dont think this is correct option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: host + '/datas',
    beforeSend: function() {
    // Add loader here
        $(placeholder).addClass('loading');
    },
   complete: function() {
    //hide loader here/
        $(placeholder).removeClass('loading');
    },
   success:function(datas){

        datas.forEach (function (data) {

            var HTML = [];
            HTML.push('<tr class="datas">');
            HTML.push('<td>' + data.email + '</td>');
            HTML.push('<td>' + name.email + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('</tr>');
            $('tbody').append(reservasHTML.join(''));

        })
   }
});
```

hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you give the image an id of `image_id` ,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: host + '/datas',
    beforeSend: function(){
    // Code to show the image . e.g.
     $('#image_id').show();
    },
    success:function(datas) {

    // Code to hide image again / completely make it display-none
    $('#image_id').hide // or $('#image_id').css("display","none");
        reservas.forEach (function (data) {
     //   ........
        })
    }
});
```